# How to capture exact text input in textarea and display it in a table?

Tags: php, html, css

[image]I am creating a programming forum and I am having trouble containing the retrieved text from the database. my textarea looks like this

```
<textarea name = "PostText" style = "width: 90%; height:480px; resize:none; direction: ltr; unicode-bidi: bidi-override;text-align:left;"required>
</textarea>
```

unicode-bidi: bidi-override captures the code how it is entered but I can not make word-wrap function correctly when using them both. So the first question is how can capture the exact text in the textarea and and display it in a table.
My td tag looks like this

```
<td style = "margin:0 auto; text-align:left;"><pre>'.htmlspecialchars($post_).'</pre></td>
```

The pre tag displays the text exactly how it was entered but will not wrap correctly and overflows its container.

**How to capture exact text input in textarea and display it in a table?**

Comment: Like here on Stackoverflow, add `overflow` property.

Comment: Is the textarea inside a <form></form> tag and do you want to get that text to use it in another page after having clicked the "submit" button on the form? or is something else happening?

Comment: Yes its a forum post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend storing as you store now (just insert to table as is), and when you display the text that you got from database, output it like this:

```
<td style = "margin:0 auto; text-align:left;">'.nl2br($post_).'</td>
```

The PHP `nl2br` function converts line-breaks (that are stored in DB) to new-line HTML tags.

Comment: I still have the same result. as when I use the pre tags the word-wrap doesnt break the long string.Other than that the formating is correct.

Comment: Do you want to keep the wrapping in database the way text was wrapped in textarea? Mind that "word wraps" and "new lines" are not the same.

Comment: Yes. So what I am calling word-wrap is takeing 1 line of text that exceeds the x width  breaks it and starts new line?  width:100%; word-wrap: break-word;

Comment: This is hardly possible. When browser wraps a line in textarea, a line break symbol does not appear in the place where wrapping occurred. So there is no indication of a wrapped line in the textarea's value. Hence, it is not possible to retrieve it.

Comment: Thank you I looked a little deeper into the nl2br function and I came up with this for the resolve.                                                                                                                  `$newtext = wordwrap(nl2br($post_),120,"\n",true);                                      <td style = "margin:0 auto; text-align:left;">'.$newtext.'</td>`. That does exactly what I need thank you sir have a nice day!

Comment: Great, I did not about the function wordwrap, this is useful.

Comment: [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) Yes its very usefull I am surprised 1 of these web design masters did not refer me to this function instead of giving me down votes for trying to learn here.

Answer (score 0):

Add overflow with determination of width:

```
<style>
    td pre{
      width: 10%;
    }
    pre{      
      overflow: auto;
    }
  </style>
```

Checkout this [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/yakabigego/edit?html,output)

Comment: Adding the width and pre style changes it but does not break a large string correctly. The picture I posted is how I entered the text in the textarea.